# DNF and CNF missing law/rule

Tags: boolean-algebra, conjunctive-normal-form, disjunctive-normal-form

I have tried simplify some expressions to DNF and CNF but I'm stuck in one step and I can't find some rule or law what can I apply on it. I used Wolfram and found that my expression is not in DNF/CNF yet.

On DNF I'm stuck here: [image: My expression]
but the DNF is:

[image: final DNF]

On CNF I'm stuck here:

[image: my CNF expresison]
but the CNF from calculators is:

[image: founded CNF]

Please can someone help me with some tip, rule or law what can by applied to solve the problem? I spent hours with it but with no progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

**Adjacency**

$PQ+PQ'=P$

and

**Absorption**

$P+PQ=P$

Applied to your first expression:

$$C'D'+CD+B'D'+BD \overset{Adjacency \ x \ 2}{=}$$

$$BC'D'+B'C'D'+CD+B'D'+BCD+BC'D \overset{Absorption \ x \ 2}{=}$$

$$BC'D'+CD+B'D'+BC'D \overset{Adjacency}{=}$$

$$BC'+CD+B'D'$$

Comment: Thats gr8, i try something similar but with some mistakes :) Thanks a lot, save my day. Havent you any other super advice for that CNF expression? :)

Comment: @kampus For the CNF: The $A + B'+C+D)$ term gets absorbed by the $A + C+D$ term, and the $A+B'+C'+D'$ term gets absorbed by the $A + C'+D'$ term.  Also, I note that there are two $B+C'+D'$ terms at the end .. one can be eliminated by Idempotence.

Comment: Thank you so much, i have not notice that i can do such absorbtion.
Cookie for both answers, you have save me :)